# upgrade artifactory from 3.5.2 to 5.4.4

Tags: artifactory

we are working a upgrading jFrog Artifactory from 3.5.2 to 5.4.5, after following upgrade steps we found that the Artifactory just doesn't load artifactory.war and access.war, only tomcat is started.
No error logs in catalina.out, the tail -f operation doesn't pop up any new error message.
Anybody give me a hand if ever upgrade Artifactory from 3.5.2 to 5.4.5 before?

Thanks.
-Neo

Comment: the guide i used - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory    Some background info:

1) Our artifactory is integrated with Crowd for SSO and using Postgresql
2) JDK is upgraded to 1.8
3) I’ve done check in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-SinglePackageTypeRepositories and all our repo contains a single type artifacts

Comment: Which type of installation? (zip, rpm, etc...)
Have you tried to go directly from 3.5.2 --> 5.4.5 or did you go to a middle version in the middle?

Comment: Also, do you have any errors in the catalina.out or localhost.log files? (Tomcat logs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've solved the problem by:

manually copied artifactory.war from /opt/artifactory/4.0.0/webapps/artifactory.war => /opt/artifactory/4.0.0/tomcat/webapps/ artifactory.war

and then tomcat loaded the wars

@Ariel - thanks for your post - my installation type is zip, i tried 3.5.2=>4 or 3.5.2=>5.x but didn't lucky enough until i found the manual workaround above

Thanks